# Unable to refresh the ListView with customAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I have been working and messing with my code from last two days.

I have a List View in a Fragment and a Button .
On clicking a button i add the data to List View entered through Dialog 
What I am unable to do is refresh the ListView after clicking Ok Button.

Here is my Code

However it loads when i exit the app and resume again

Any Help will be appreciated

```
 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");
    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(input)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            String Value = input.getText().toString();
                            String normalizednumber = NormalizePhoneUtilities
                                    .normalizePhoneNumber(Value);
                            ContactModel contactModel = new ContactModel(
                                    "Hitesh", normalizednumber, String
                                            .valueOf(3));
                            ContactsDatabaseWorker sm = new ContactsDatabaseWorker(
                                    getActivity());

                            sm.AddSmartContact(contactModel);
                            databaseWorker = new ContactsDatabaseWorker(
                                    getActivity());
                            // LinkedList<Cursor> list = new
                            // LinkedList<Cursor>();
                            // list=databaseWorker.getAllData();

                            run = new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(
                                            getActivity(), databaseWorker
                                                    .getAllData());

                                    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    listview.invalidateViews();
                                    listview.refreshDrawableState();
                                    listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
                                }
                            };
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(run);

                            isModal = false;

                        }

                    })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {

                        }
                    }).create();
}






@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (isModal) // AVOID REQUEST FEATURE CRASH
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smartalert_fragment,
                container, false);
        listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvSmartAlert);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smartalert_fragment, container,
            false);
    Button bAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bAddContact);
    bAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvSmartAlert);

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                    databaseWorker.getAllData());
            listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged ();` in adapter.

Comment: Not working .I am putting it in bindView of simplecursoradapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your CursorAdapter has a [swapCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#swapCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) method, which you can use each time you get an updated cursor.